# how to edit a file in java that becomes read-only at run-time

Tags: java, runtime, perforce, editing, readonly

I have to edit a file at run time. the file in question is a java properties file.
Basically, i am storing a value in this props file for later use.
However, when i check-in this file in perforce, this becomes a read-only and at run time the file cannot be edited and an exception is thrown as access-denied.
The reason is that this file cannot be edited as it has now become a read-only file after checking in.
Please can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: if you have to do this, chances are the design is wrong

Comment: I assume that this could be a design issue. but, what possibly could go wrong with this approach. any use case where this can go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build should not have a runtime dependence on a file in your *source* tree.

You instead should *copy* the necessary file from your source tree into your build tree as part of the build process (where it then can freely change the permissions to be writable).  Your build then should depend on *that* copy of the file.